# How to get bucardo 5.6.0 to perform replication?

Tags: postgresql, bucardo

I'm trying to get Bucardo to perform multimaster replication between 2 postgres 12 databases.  I believe that everything is installed correctly and I can configure replication.  But, nothing happens.  Below is a sample of the code I've tried (but I've tried a lot of variations).  Do you all have any suggestions?

```
bucardo add db base dbname=postgres host=192.168.1.15 user=bricks pass=bricks
bucardo add db site dbname=postgres host=192.168.1.16 user=bricks pass=bricks   
bucardo add dbgroup bricks here:source away:source
bucardo list dbgroups
#
bucardo add table bricks.brick_20201204 db=here
bucardo add table bricks.brick_20201204 db=away
#
bucardo add sync bricks_here_20201204 \
   status=active \
   conflict_strategy=bucardo_latest \
   autokick=true \
   dbgroup=bricks \
   checktime=5 \
   tables=bricks.brick_20201204

bucardo add sync bricks_away_20201204 \
   status=active \
   conflict_strategy=bucardo_latest \
   autokick=true \
   dbgroup=bricks \
   checktime=5 \
   tables=bricks.brick_20201204
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you must restart bucardo after each action.  Very frustrating.